# PSQL - How to filter out if a column value equals a specific string

Tags: python, postgresql

I created a database with column called option where the value is a varchar of either 'Call', 'Put', or None. When I set up the database I made the default value None if there was no Call or Put.

I'm trying to filter out the rows that contain 'Call' or 'Put' for option. However, when I write the query

SELECT *
FROM holdings h
WHERE h.option != 'Call'
AND h.option != 'Put';

```
I get this error:
    curr.execute('SELECT option FROM holdings WHERE option != 'Call';')
                                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I try to use NOT LIKE '%Call%' I get this error:

```
curr.execute('SELECT option FROM holdings AS h WHERE option NOT LIKE '%Call%';')
NameError: name 'Call' is not defined
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

Code looks like this:

```
import psycopg2
import csv
conn = psycopg2.connect('dbname = db user = asmith')
curr = conn.cursor()
curr.execute('SELECT option FROM holdings h WHERE option NOT LIKE '%Call%';')
tups = curr.fetchall()
for tup in tups:
    print tup
```

Edit:
When I run these two lines:

```
curr.execute('SELECT * FROM holdings h WHERE option = \'Call\' OR option = \'Put\';') 
curr.execute('SELECT * FROM holdings h WHERE option != \'Call\' AND option != \'Put\';')
```

The first query gives me all the rows with a Call or Put, but when I run the second query I get nothing, even though it should theoretically give me all of the rows with option that are None. Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: can you paste the actual error? the ^ will point to the character that has problem.

Comment: Please paste whole line of your code. The sql syntax is ok. I think there is a problem elsewhere- maybe you are using single quotes outside the query also? Maybe try like: curr.execute("SELECT option .... != 'Call'

Comment: now your question is much clearer.

Comment: You should to mark as accepted the right answer to the your **original** question. If you have any additional question(s) then create another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Syntax error here:

`curr.execute('SELECT option FROM holdings h WHERE option NOT LIKE '%Call%';')`

String 1 is `'SELECT option FROM holdings h WHERE option NOT LIKE '`, breaks with `'`  (before `%Call%`), then some variable named Call (which Your compiler cannot find) and then String 2 `';'`

You have to escape `'` with backslash like this:

`curr.execute('SELECT option FROM holdings AS h WHERE option NOT LIKE \'%Call%\';')`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a logic thing but do you know why putting: WHERE option != \'Call\' AND option != \'Put\' does not return anything, but I want it to return the Nones. If I put OR instead of AND then it returns both Calls and Puts

Answer (score 0):

There is logic error in statement. You should write this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM holdings h WHERE h.option != 'Call' OR h.option != 'Put';
```

or this:

```
SELECT * FROM holdings h WHERE h.option NOT IN ( 'Call' , 'Put');
```

Thanks.

Comment: I tried both of them and I'm getting a carrot pointing at 'Call' for both with invalid syntax

Comment: What is the database? Maybe you should try "<>" instead of "!="?

Comment: `arg != val1 or arg != val2` is always `true` except if `arg is null` or if `val1 = val2`.